# Drupal, Views, Exposed filter, make tags unselectable

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal Views with an exposed filter with several tags.  I would like to make some tags "unselectable", if they cannot be combined with the already selected tags. (They would give empty results page.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery can disable tags in form. what do you mean by "if they cannot be combined with the already selected tags"?